# display utf-8 persian text use weka text categorization code

Tags: java, utf-8, weka

I'm new in java. I want to convert my text file in ARFF format but my texts is Persian and NetBeans can not display these in a good format (utf-8 format )
in this topic:

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+Weka#UTF-8

said that i should run this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -classpath ...
```

but i want to use this command in my code. I do not know how should i run java in command.
Can anyone tell me how should i do this  line in my code?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Weka, since you are already using NetBeans, it's better if you change NetBeans configuration to UTF-8

> 1. Open `etc` folder inside the Netbeans directory (path where you
>      installed NetBeans).   Edit `netbeans.conf` using Notepad or any
>      text editor.
> 2. Look for this field: `netbeans_default_options add`   If it is
>      already present, change it to
>      `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
> 3. Else, add a new line at the end of the file:
>
>    ```
>    netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
>    ```
> 4. Restart Netbeans.